# Most efficient way to tell if a camera is available?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the most efficient way to check if a **physical** camera is available with C# in Unity, given that the actual camera image is not needed?

EDIT: I am currently using this, but as I have to check every frame any improvement is great:

```
var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes();
if (!image.IsAvailable){ //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Show your *inefficient* way first so that we can improve it.

Comment: I have added my current code, any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a WebCamTexture, it has an isPlaying variable.

> isPlaying **Returns if the camera is currently playing.**

It also has a list of devices.

> devices   **Return a list of available devices.**

I don't have experience using this, but it does sound quite relevant.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details. What do you mean 'is available'?
You can check Camera.allcameras returns all enabled cameras in the scene.
You can check Camera.current the camera we are currently rendering with, for low-level render control only (Read Only).

or

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This is Main Camera in the scene
    Camera m_MainCamera;
    //This is the second Camera and is assigned in inspector
    public Camera m_CameraTwo;

    void Start()
    {
        //This gets the Main Camera from the scene
        m_MainCamera = Camera.main;
        //This enables Main Camera
        m_MainCamera.enabled = true;
        //Use this to disable secondary Camera
        m_CameraTwo.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

You can check the unity documentation at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

Comment: As I specified in my question, I am talking about a physical camera. Not a camera in any scene.

Comment: If you are only checking if the camera is available, then you only need to check it one time, since it would be redundant to check every frame once you already checked it once.

Comment: Yes, however I actually do need to check almost every frame as it may stop being available at any time. It also may start being available at any time, so it would check if that is true as well

Comment: unless its becoming available and unavailable at completely random points, then there is something external that is causing them to change state. I would simply suggest to check availability once those states have changed.